# A field extension K/F is biquadratic if [K:F] = 4 and if $K$ is generated by the roots of two irreducible quadratic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Artin claims that every biquadratic extension has the form $F(\alpha,\beta)$，where $\alpha^2 = a$ and $\beta^2 = b$ with $a,b\in F$.

I do not think this is true, just consider $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt {2}$, $\alpha^2$ clearly is not in $\mathbb Q$. Am I right? I think he means that $(\sqrt{2})^2$ should be in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Well, with $\alpha = 1+\sqrt{2}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\beta)$...

Comment: I totally agree, but I do not think this is obvious from his definition since he consider $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be roots of two quadratic irreducible polynomials.

Comment: write your roots $x_1 = \frac{-B+\Delta^{1/2}}{2A}$ and $y_1 = \frac{-B_2+\Delta_2^{1/2}}{2A_2}$, and find a way to write the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,y_1)$ as $\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/2},b^{1/2})$

Comment: Artin is saying it can always be written in the form $F(\alpha,\beta)$. You may choose to write it in some other form, but you *can* write it in Artin's form.